# "Text to Columns" a field in R using different variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to delimit a list in R using a couple of different values, and I feel like I'm severely overcomplicating what I need to do.

I'd like to split out anything in the list that's "positive" (ie. that starts the list or has a + sign in front it) in a Positive column.

Anything with a - sign into a Negative column.

Anything that is like c("EmilyP", "EmilyS") into an Emily column

and anything that is c("Red", "Blue") into a Color column.

I have tried both dplyr and tidyr and can't make this work, then I started working on a loop and that seems way to complex.

Can anyone suggest a better method?

(Input and Outputs below).

```
input <- structure(list(Team.Name = c("Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 4", 
"Team 5", "Team 6"), Members = c("Frank + Terry - Joan - Bob + EmilyS + Red", 
"Frank + Bob - Neil - Janet - Tim + EmilyP + Blue", "Frank + Blue - Joan - Bob + EmilyP + Red", 
"Tom + Jerry - Bill - Jenny", "Tess + Jean + Jill + EmilyS", 
"Bill + Bob + Red")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

and I'm trying to get this:

```
output <- structure(list(Team.Name = c("Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 4", 
"Team 5", "Team 6"), Positive = c("Frank + Terry", "Frank + Bob", 
"Frank", "Tom + Jerry", "Tess + Jean + Jill", "Bill + Bob"), 
    Negative = c("Joan - Bob", "Neil - Janet - Tim", "Joan - Bob", 
    "Bill - Jenny", "", ""), Emily = c("EmilyS", "EmilyP", "EmilyP", 
    "", "EmilyS", ""), Color = c("Red", "Blue", "Red + Blue", 
    "", "", "Red")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Will this have the same pattern

Comment: In your output, the 2nd row "EmilyP" is also grouped with 'Positive' while it is not in first row.  Does the `P` at the end signifies positive

Comment: I think some of the 'output' elements are not clear or have the 'Color' repeated with 'Positive'

Comment: @akrun - sorry, the pattern won't always be the same and I've fixed the output so it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got for now. First, I split members and created a data frame with `map_dfr()`. Then, I worked on some string manipulation. The first member in each group does not have `+`. So I added that to the first member. I replaced `+` or `-` before `Emily` followed by a capital letter with `Emily`. I also replaced `+` or `-` before a color name with `color`. Then, I separated the column, `value` with `separate()`. For each group, I combined all names with `toString()`. Finally, I converted the data to a wide-format data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

map_dfr(.x = stri_split_regex(str = input$Members, pattern = "\\s(?=[+|-])"),
        .f = enframe,
        .id = "id") %>% 
mutate(value = if_else(!substr(x = value, start = 1, stop =1) %in% c("+", "-"),
                       paste("+ ", value, sep = ""), value),
       value = if_else(grepl(x = value, pattern = "Emily[A-Z]"),
                             sub(x = value, pattern = "[+|-]", replacement = "Emily"),
                             value),
       value = if_else(sub(x = value, pattern = "[+|-]\\s", replacement = "") %in% stri_trans_totitle(colors(distinct = TRUE)),
                       sub(x = value, pattern = "[+|-]", replacement = "color"),
                       value)) %>%
separate(col = "value", into = c("type", "value"), sep = "\\s") %>% 
group_by(id, type) %>%  
summarise(value = toString(value)) %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols = "id", names_from = "type", values_from = "value")

#  id    `-`              `+`              color     Emily 
#  <chr> <chr>            <chr>            <chr>     <chr> 
#1 1     Joan, Bob        Frank, Terry     Red       EmilyS
#2 2     Neil, Janet, Tim Frank, Bob       Blue      EmilyP
#3 3     Joan, Bob        Frank            Blue, Red EmilyP
#4 4     Bill, Jenny      Tom, Jerry       NA        NA    
#5 5     NA               Tess, Jean, Jill NA        EmilyS
#6 6     NA               Bill, Bob        Red       NA
```